# How can I disable xb_doublewrite?

Tags: mysql, innodb, percona-server, mysql-5.7

Getting error while service restart.

> [ERROR] InnoDB: A parallel doublewrite file /test/mysql/xb_doublewrite found on startup.

Answer (score 2):

You have to look in `my.cnf` for the variable  [innodb_parallel_doublewrite_path](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/performance/xtradb_performance_improvements_for_io-bound_highly-concurrent_workloads.html#innodb_parallel_doublewrite_path)

You should also set this

```
[mysqld]
innodb_doublewrite=0
```

Then, restart mysql

After restarting mysql, you can then delete `/test/mysql/xb_doublewrite`

## CAVEAT

What is the purpose of this feature ?

According to [Percona Server 5.7 performance improvements](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/17/percona-server-5-7-performance-improvements/)

> [Parallel doublewrite buffer](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/performance/xtradb_performance_improvements_for_io-bound_highly-concurrent_workloads.html#parallel-doublewrite-buffer). For ages, MySQL has had only one
> doublewrite buffer for flushing data pages. So even if you had several
> threads for flushing you couldn’t efficiently use them – doublewrite
> quickly became a bottleneck. We’ve changed that by attaching two
> doublewrite buffers to each buffer pool instance: one for each type of
> page flushing (LRU and flush list). This completely avoids any
> doublewrite contention, regardless of the flusher thread count. We’ve
> also moved the doublewrite buffer out of the system tablespace so you
> can now configure its location.

So, if you do want it gone, remove [innodb_parallel_doublewrite_path](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.7/performance/xtradb_performance_improvements_for_io-bound_highly-concurrent_workloads.html#innodb_parallel_doublewrite_path) if it is there. Although not recommnded, you must add [**innodb_doublewrite=0**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_doublewrite) to disable the InnoDB Double Write Buffer altogether.

Comment: And run the risk of "torn pages" in the case of a power failure?

Comment: If you have Percona Server, the best you can do is having the `innodb_parallel_doublewrite_path` set to a different partition/disk (preferably XFS) for the `xb_doublewrite` tablespace. That will split the fsync calls done by the doublewrite threads.